# Can't import A-frame into component - Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-cli, aframe

I have a project created with `angular-cli` where I have installed `aframe` via `npm install aframe --save`, and when I try to import it in the component via `import 'aframe';` it causes the following error:

> Failed to execute `registerElement` on `Document`: Registration failed for type `a-node`. A type with that name is already registered.

In this case, the only way to make it work is by importing the library in the `<head>` tag of the `index.html` file. Instead I would like to access `aframe` object3D to [modify](https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/guides/using-with-threejs.html) objects entities, as shown here:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function () {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

but unluckily I am not able to make it work. Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you have to get it properly working in Angular2:

1. Edit your angular-cli.json and add the path to the scripts node:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/aframe/dist/aframe-master.js"
],
```

2. Download the typings from https://github.com/devpaul/aframe-typings/blob/master/src/AFRAME.d.ts.
3. Reference the typings in your component with:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/AFRAME.d.ts" />
```

or install the typings globally in your tsconfig.json:

```
"files": [
    "typings/AFRAME.d.ts"
  ]
```

Comment: AFRAME.d.ts throws cannot find namespace `THREE`. Any idea?