# Using aframe with Angular 2

Tags: angular, aframe

I'm trying to use Aframe in my angular 2 project.

I imported the library in my index.html but I still can't use the aframe directive, for example:

```
<a-scene>
    <a-box color="red"></a-box>
  </a-scene>
```

Throws the error:

```
Template parse errors:
'a-box' is not a known element:
1. If 'a-box' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

How I can import such library to my angular 2 project and use it's directives?

Comment: check the network tab on your web browser and see whether the library is  loaded

Comment: I have asked a similar question a while ago. Check it out, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163088/cant-import-a-frame-into-component-angular2

Comment: Thanks @d_z90! Did you had any cannot find namespace `THREE`. error? Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, I did but I remember that after updating the all packages the problem disappeared.

Comment: @TheUnreal, did you find a solution, can't figure out what is going on for hours... :(

Comment: not yet @AdrianSol

Comment: @TheUnreal same here, can you please update the question if you will figure it out, I will do the same I something will work

Comment: @TheUnreal have a look, hope it helps you. https://github.com/adriansol/Angular-CLI-Aframe

Answer (score 2):

I fixed doing this:

I Try adding:

import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';

to app.module.ts

then i add it to the NgModule Schemas:

@NgModule({
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]})

that will fix it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';` to app.module.ts