# Angular.io + AFRAME. Typings error with Three.js "Cannot find namespace 'THREE'"

Tags: angular, aframe

I am trying to add the A-Frame into Angular.io (4.0) by defining it inside `angular-cli.json`

```
"scripts": [
     "../node_modules/aframe/dist/aframe-master.js"
  ],
```

And get the following error

```
polyfills.bundle.js:22719 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'attributeChangedCallback' of object '[object HTMLElement]'
    at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:22719:46
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at HTMLDocument.document.registerElement (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:22706:23)
    at module.exports.registerElement (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:21:8), <anonymous>:72793:19)
    at Object.94.../lib/three (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:21:8), <anonymous>:71194:18)
    at s (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:21:8), <anonymous>:1:620)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:21:8), <anonymous>:1:671)
    at Object.144.../package (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:21:8), <anonymous>:75638:1)
    at s (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:21:8), <anonymous>:1:620)
    at e (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:21:8), <anonymous>:1:791)
```

So I add [aframe typings](https://github.com/devpaul/aframe-typings/blob/master/src/AFRAME.d.ts) and import them inside `tsconfig.app.json`

```
 "files": [
    "typings/AFRAME.d.ts"
  ]
```

The first error becomes resolved and the new one appears for multiple lines like:

```
ERROR in /Users/Illusion/Desktop/charterdart/charterdart-experience/src/typings/AFRAME.d.ts (18,45): Cannot find namespace 'THREE'.

ERROR in /Users/Illusion/Desktop/charterdart/charterdart-experience/src/typings/AFRAME.d.ts (136,13): Cannot find namespace 'THREE'.

ERROR in /Users/Illusion/Desktop/charterdart/charterdart-experience/src/typings/AFRAME.d.ts (144,30): Cannot find namespace 'THREE'.
```

Can you please suggest the proper way how to work it out or any other approach to get the things work.

**Update:**

I've noticed that if typings are not uploaded, I can `declare var THREE : any;` inside the component and even implement any `Three.js` logic inside `ngInit()`, but still can't target the Aframe...

Comment: typings have nothing to do with the original error, how do you use a-frame in your application?

Comment: Until this moment, there was no use of A-Frame inside of it, I just installed from npm, and did loaded it into angular.cli.json. As I mentioned in update, if I don't load typings I can reference to the THREE, but can't reference to AFrame or AFRAME like it's declared inside the code.

Comment: _and did loaded it into angular.cli.json_ - why did you do that?

Comment: @Maximus it's the way I know to import javascript modules into angular typescript world. Is there a more proper way?

Comment: where did you read about that?

Comment: I did find this approach under the following issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163088/cant-import-a-frame-into-component-angular2

Comment: I see, unfortunately can't help here

Comment: @Maximus, no problem. Thank you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:
 1. including

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

in the index.html, but before including zone.js,

2.     `import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA }  from '@angular/core';`

in your app.ts
3. declare   `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]`
in your @NgModule

My working code in angular.io:
https://embed.plnkr.co/SUXTDiWOOZz5FBfymXk5 
Its completely unfinished, but aframe works there, in the simple preview tab. I'm kinda new to angular, so it may be crappy.

Comment: Thank you man, I've taken your approach and worked on it a little bit to make it work with Angular-CLI. If you are interested check out https://github.com/adriansol/Angular-CLI-Aframe. P.S: I'll award you a bounty in 14h since SO doesn't allow me atm.

Comment: np, I'm really glad i could help :)